# Fullcalendar events not refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, fullcalendar

I try to show the calendar inside a modal. The user will click on a button in which it holds a parameter to filter calendar events.

Here is my code:

```
<td><button type="button" class='select btn btn-xs' onclick="selectSchedule(this)" data-type="staff">Open Modal</button></td>
<td><button type="button" class='select btn btn-xs' onclick="selectSchedule(this)" data-type="manager">Open Modal</button></td>

var type = $(elem).data('type');

 $.ajax({
            url: '/Staff/GetSchedule',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { StaffType: type}, 
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#schedule').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
                    },
                    events: data
            },

 public JsonResult GetSchedule(string StaffType)
        {
            //codes
        }
```

It works well at the first click in which it shows all the filtered events. But when the user clicked the second button, the calendar is not refreshed. It still shows the same events as before.

I also tried to use this way but it didn't work. the same error which is the calendar is not updating the new events. but this time it only pass through controller one time even when i clicked these button twice. Here is the code:

```
 $('#schedule').fullCalendar({
                    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                        $.ajax({
                             url: '/Staff/GetSchedule',
                            data: { StaffType: type},
                            success: function (data) {
                                callback(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


public JsonResult GetSchedule(string StaffType)
        {
            List<ScheduleInputModel> Schedule= new List<ScheduleInputModel>();
            List<ScheduleDetail> ScheduleList = new List<ScheduleDetail>();

            ScheduleList = db.Schedule.Where(x => x.Type== StaffType).ToList();

            foreach (ScheduleDetail item in ScheduleList )
            {

                ScheduleInputModel ScheduleDetails= new ScheduleInputModel();
                ScheduleDetails.id = item.Id;
                ScheduleDetails.start = item.DateIn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z");
                ScheduleDetails.end = item.DateOut.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z");
                ScheduleDetails.title = item.RadiologyExam.Description;
                ScheduleDetails.editable = true;
                Schedule.Add(ScheduleDetails);
            }

                var requestList = Schedule.ToList();
            return Json(requestList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: you missed out some code linking your button to your ajax code, so we don't know if it's selecting the  `type` value correctly. Also you may want to try destroying and re-creating the calendar again each time. Or a better alternative would be to keep the calendar, and just change the events each time the button's pressed - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/refetchEvents - those are the methods you'd need.

Comment: selected type value is correct and in the controller, it did shows correct list of data. but the calendar doesnt show the same data as in controller

Comment: Ok so follow one of my two suggestions above, then.

Comment: i tried both suggestion but it seems didnt work because the error is still same

Comment: The code you've just posted...show it in context please. How does it obtain the correct value for `type`? Bear in mind you should be only running this code once when your modal is created, and never again. Also where is your call to refetchEvents which would trigger it to get the new events? Your sample is incomplete, so I can't say whether you did it correctly or not. If you're still stuck, I can try to write an answer for it.

Comment: oh there is something here i just found out. when i click the button, it fires out multiple times

Comment: well again I can't say why that is because the code is shown out of context.

Comment: the last snippet of code you've shown is, on its own, correct. But the problem seems to be related to how and when you're running that code. That's the missing piece you haven't made clear above. If you show that, we can probably help you better.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: There's no harm showing us the server code I guess, although we know that basically works. But no I meant the rest of the Javascript code. Get rid of your original code and show us all the relevant Javascript code as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't turned off jQuery AJAX caching sitewide, then add to the AJAX call:

```
 $('#schedule').fullCalendar({
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                         url: '/Staff/GetSchedule',
                        data: { StaffType: type},
                        cache: false, //CHANGED
                        success: function (data) {
                            callback(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

I noticed one call to the GetSchedule is done as a POST, and one as a GET operation.  GET operations can be posted, [taken from here](https://www.sitepoint.com/key-differences-post/):

> GET is intended to be used when you are reading
>   information to display on the page. Browsers will cache the result
>   from a GET request and if the same GET request is made again then they
>   will display the cached result rather than rerunning the entire
>   request.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you the correct structure:

HTML snippet:

```
<td><button type="button" class='select btn btn-xs' data-type="staff">Open Modal</button></td>
<td><button type="button" class='select btn btn-xs' data-type="manager">Open Modal</button></td>
```

JavaScript - make sure you run this code once when your page is created:

```
var type = null;
var calendar = null;

$(function() {
 $(".select").click() { //unobtrusive "click" event handler instead of inline
   type = $(this).data("type");
   if (calendar == null) { getCalendar(); } //first run
   else { calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents"); } //subsequent changes
 });
});

function getCalendar()
{
   calendar = $('#schedule');
   calendar.fullCalendar({
     events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
       $.ajax({
         url: '/Staff/GetSchedule',
         data: { StaffType: type},
         cache: false, //don't cache results
         success: function (data) {
           callback(data);
         }
       });
     }
  });
}
```